# POST Content-Length of 51110424 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

I'm testing my website in localhost. When I send voluntarily a big file instead of a little picture, I don't have the error message that I wrote for this case but an ugly "*Warning: POST Content-Length of 51110424 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040 bytes in Unknown on line 0*" at the top of the website.

I read I can edit the limit in php.ini but there is always the possibility for the user to send a larger file. Is there a solution to avoid this "Warning" and see my error message instead ?

Thank you

Comment: As I said, if I edit limite size, I juste postpone my problem. There is always an user to send a bigger file

Comment: There has to be a limit you don't want users to exceed. Do you really want users uploading a 20 Petabyte file to your website? Also please show your code. You mention a warning but without seeing where that is it is difficult to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is not really an error, but a warning. You should only see it in debug installations with `display_errors` enabled in php.ini.

In your code, you should test the `'error'` field of the `$_FILES` object, and you should get the value `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` (1) if the file size exceeds the maximum specified in php.ini.

See the [documentation of error codes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) for further details.

Comment: Oh OK I understand, Thank you for your help